# Getting node view mode in field preprocess

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am trying to get the view mode of a node to use it in a field twig file by writing this function in my_theme, but it doesn't work:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
 if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
  $variables['view_mode_2'] = $node->view_mode;
 }
}
```

I don't know if the variable is correct, but when I write some echo code I see that already the if condition isn't fulfilled.

EDIT: the if condition is only fulfilled when the node is open, but not when its teaser is shown as part of a view on the front page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a field template the view mode is stored here:

```
$variables['element']['#view_mode']
```

So you could check in preprocess, if the node is not displayed as teaser:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#view_mode'] != 'teaser')  {
    // node is not displayed on the front page
  }
}
```

The same condition in a field twig:

**field.html.twig**

```
{% if element['#view_mode'] != 'teaser' %}
  node is not displayed on the front page
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, that's what I was searching! If anybody wants to know why this could be useful: My content type article has a text field for a subheadline. In order to wrap this headline with h-tags I created a custom field-xxx.html.twig file, but the problem is that the subheadline needs h3 tags in a teaser context, but h2 tags when showed as a full page. So the twig template is now checking the view mode and giving h2 or h3 tags depending on the view mode.

Comment: You can use the same condition in a field twig. I add this to the answer.

Comment: So you don't need the preprocess anymore?

Comment: Yes, you've asked about preprocess, but for what you've described in the comment you don't need preprocess.

Comment: Cool, good to know!