# Twig template name for field when content type is viewed in particular view mode

Tags: theming, 8

Based on [twig template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) I have created twig for any field type of given content:

```
field--node--myContentType.html.twig
```

Is it possible to use different twig when `myContentType` is visible in "full" view mode? I've already tried:

```
field--node--myContentType--full.html.twig
```

But it **does not** triggers. I can use `node--myContentType.html.twig` and `node--myContentType--full.html.twig` for full view of the node, but it doesn't work for `field` twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field templates have no name suggestion for the view mode.

From the linked page:

> This page lists the conventions used for the base html structure, the
>   page, regions, blocks, nodes, fields, and other core components. (It's
>   good to know that it is possible to create custom template name
>   suggestions using function [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x).)

You have to create a custom name suggestion.

You find the view mode in the variables of the field: [Getting node view mode in field preprocess](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224321/getting-node-view-mode-in-field-preprocess)